# For each column representing a year, find values below 0.0004832817, sum them all up and output a new row with the added values for each year

Tags: r, filter, sum

I have a data.frame `DK_M.Change`:

```
'data.frame':   1290019 obs. of  100 variables:
$ Mass1  : num  0.12229 0.04995 0.05843 0.00104 0.53576 ...
$ Mass2  : num  0.11817 0.04826 0.05646 0.00101 0.51769 ...
$ Mass3  : num  0.114179 0.046633 0.054558 0.000975 0.500226
```

I need to find/filter all masses < 0.0004832817 which I have assigned to `m.PM10` in each Mass column. The integer following the Mass prefix in each column, signifies a year. Then I want to add the mass of all the obervations lower than `m.PM10` for each Mass column and I want R to output a small 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  100 variables: with the newly calculated masses.

Tibble of `DK_M.Change`

```
DK_M.Change$Mas~  $Mass2  $Mass3  $Mass4  $Mass5  $Mass6  $Mass7  $Mass8
          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1           0.122   1.18e-1 1.14e-1 1.10e-1 1.07e-1 1.03e-1 9.95e-2 9.62e-2
 2           0.0499  4.83e-2 4.66e-2 4.51e-2 4.35e-2 4.21e-2 4.07e-2 3.93e-2
 3           0.0584  5.65e-2 5.46e-2 5.27e-2 5.09e-2 4.92e-2 4.76e-2 4.60e-2
 4           0.00104 1.01e-3 9.75e-4 9.42e-4 9.10e-4 8.80e-4 8.50e-4 8.21e-4
 5           0.536   5.18e-1 5.00e-1 4.83e-1 4.67e-1 4.51e-1 4.36e-1 4.21e-1
 6           1.12    1.08e+0 1.04e+0 1.01e+0 9.76e-1 9.43e-1 9.11e-1 8.80e-1
 7           1.17    1.13e+0 1.09e+0 1.05e+0 1.02e+0 9.82e-1 9.49e-1 9.17e-1
 8           4.04    3.90e+0 3.77e+0 3.64e+0 3.52e+0 3.40e+0 3.29e+0 3.18e+0
 9          19.8     1.91e+1 1.85e+1 1.79e+1 1.73e+1 1.67e+1 1.61e+1 1.56e+1
10           0.0343  3.31e-2 3.20e-2 3.09e-2 2.99e-2 2.89e-2 2.79e-2 2.69e-2
```

I tried this, and it's doing something.... I am just not sure what.. I get values that are way higher than what I am expecting.

`Mass_PM10_ev<- DK_M.Change %>%  summarise_all(., funs(sum(.<m.PM10)))`

If I do a few columns "manually" one by one (as the code below), then I get values that make sense,i.e.  small values in increasing order with increasing years. Can someone please help me do this for all columns automatically?

`test1<-DK_M.Change %>% select(Mass1) %>% filter(Mass1<m.PM10) %>% sum()`

I really appreciate your help, in advance thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NEWDF = DK_M.Change[,1:100] %>% 
                                lapply(function(x){
                                 x[x < m.PM10]%>% sum()
                                }) %>% do.call(what = "cbind")
```

If I understood correctly you want the first 100 years ( 100 columns) then for each column sum all values smaller than m.PM10 and then make that a new dataframe. Here the masses are the columns, if you want them to be the rows then
replace `do.call(what = "cbind")`  with `do.call(what = "rbind")`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted to do. And it works just great! @dvd280 If you have a minute, could you please explain this part of your code `x[x`, also how do I make this a dataframe? It is currently a list.

Comment: I edited for creating the dataframe. regarding the x[x question,  the [ ] symbol means subsetting. inside the[ ] brackets is a logical vector, outside it is just a regular vector, so x < m.PM10 will be just a bunch of TRUE and FALSE statements in a vector which indicate which indices of x to keep and which to discard